# Cannot make page--node--nid to work

Tags: theming

I created the *page--node-112.html.twig* template file for a
Page* node whose ID is 112. Drupal is still using the *page--page.html.twig* template file.

How can I make Drupal use the template file I created?

Comment: Is it even a valid template suggestion? Did you clear cache?

Answer (score 1):

None of the Drupal core modules and themes suggests `'page__' . $bundle`. If that suggestion is added by a module (or a theme) after the suggestions added by [`system_theme_suggestions_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_theme_suggestions_page/9.3.x), which is the hook that suggests `'page__node__' . $nid`, that suggestion is picked up first, since suggestions are checked from the last to the first.

The code that checks for which of the suggestions there is a template file is in [`ThemeManager::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeManager.php/function/ThemeManager%3A%3Arender/9.3.x).

```php
  // Check if each suggestion exists in the theme registry, and if so,
  // use it instead of the base hook. For example, a function may use
  // '#theme' => 'node', but a module can add 'node__article' as a suggestion
  // via hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter(), enabling a theme to have
  // an alternate template file for article nodes.
  foreach (array_reverse($suggestions) as $suggestion) {
    if ($theme_registry->has($suggestion)) {
      $info = $theme_registry->get($suggestion);
      break;
    }
  }
```

Without a module adding that suggestion, *page--node-112.html.twig* is not a template file Drupal core would pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [Twig Debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates), that will add comments including template file names that can be used to override less specific templates.

The comments look something like this and you can view them in source or your browser's inspector.

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'page' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * page--node--6178.html.twig
   * page--node--%.html.twig
   * page--node--article.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   x page.html.twig
-->
```

In the above example you can see my page is being rendered using page.html.twig but I have alternatives above that which could be used specific to my content type (article) or node a single id.